# Disable Ctrl+Alt Hotkeys in certain programs

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am using Sublime Text 3 which uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>$key</kbd> hotkeys for a few important functionalities, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> (for example) switches workspaces. Is there a way I can disable the OS functions of these hotkeys while I'm using Sublime Text 3?

I'm running Linux Mint 16 Petra with Cinnamon desktop, and the latest version of Sublime Text 3

Comment: this highly depends on your desktop environment. When using KDE try the command systemsettings. There you will find settings for the keyboard including hotkeys.

Comment: While it's not exactly what I was looking for, I was able to change the hotkeys through the System Settings > Keyboard menu.

Comment: Not sure if Cinnamon has anything similar, but KDE has this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79513/28489 . Also this, but does not seem to apply to Ctrl+Alt+Arrow though: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/89378-support-unbinding-of-keys/ (As in it is not captured by Sublime, at least in my tests.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply un-map the keys.

Run `dconf-editor`. Head to org.cimmamon.muffin.keybindings. And empty or change the conflicting key bindings.

I recommend you edit the keybindings in Sublime Text though.

edit

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm
```

'cause

> org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings

seems to be deprecated

[image]
/edit