# KDE Plasma: How do I pass keys like (Ctrl-F9) to specific applications

Tags: kde, plasma

I know I can globally disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> in Kwin, but I want to keep this functionality, still pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> etc to some specific applications (like IntelliJ idea).

How do I specify that when those applications have the focus those keys go to the application?

Comment: Only like this I think: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77980/suspending-the-global-kdex-windows-keyboard-shortcuts-while-specific-applicatio?rq=1

Comment: Another suggestion is to write a KWin script, so you can handle specific shortcut instead of disabling all global shortcuts for window.